# What is the best way to update One to One Polymorphic in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, polymorphism, relationship, one-to-one

I have One to One Polymorphic, I want to figure the best way to update existed relationships.

```
class Image extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get the owning imageable model.
     */
    public function imageable()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
}

class Post extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get the post's image.
     */
    public function image()
    {
        return $this->morphOne('App\Image', 'imageable');
    }
}

class User extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get the user's image.
     */
    public function image()
    {
        return $this->morphOne('App\Image', 'imageable');
    }
}
```

On Update Method in PostController

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $post       = Post::findOrFail($id);
    $post->image()->delete();
    $post->image()->save(new Image([
        'url'=> $request->input('image_url),
    ]));
}
```

> How to update Image Relationship without deleting it first?

Thanks

Comment: Will a`Post` always already have an image with this method?

Comment: Yes, always have image.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could try using `updateOrCreate` on the relationship:

```
$post->image()->updateOrCreate(
    [],
    ['url' => $request->input('image_url')]
);
```

If you are always expecting there to be an `Image` related to the `Post` you can update the `Image` instance directly:

```
$post->image->update([...]);
```

Comment: do you mean
`$post->image()->updateOrCreate(
    ['imagable_type' => 'App\Post', 'imageable_id' => $post->id],
    ['url' => $request->input('image_url')]
);`

Comment: no, the relationship should add the needed morph fields when it does the select query

Comment: I got this error `message: "Call to a member function updateOrCreate() on null"`, because I want it to create if in the database in relation record.

Comment: if there is a relationship record, `updateOrCreate()`, only work as an update method, it will create if no record.

Comment: and what are you calling `updateOrCreate` on? `$post->image()` should not be returning `null`

Comment: yes, that is why it is called `updateOrCreate` .. if one exists it updates, if one doesn't exist it will create the record

Comment: oh right, my bad. I only called `$post->image->updateOrCreate();`. Thanks for solution.